# python check if dict has any nested items

Tags: python, dictionary

What is the pythonic way of checking if a dict has nested elements

Examples

```
hasNestedElt({'a': 1, 'b': 2}) #=> False
hasNestedElt({'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 3} }) #=> True
hasNestedElt({'a': 1, 'b': ('c', 3) }) #=> False
hasNestedElt({'a': 1, 'b': ('c', 3, 'x') }) #=> False
hasNestedElt({'a': 1, 'b': ('c', (3, 'x')) }) #=> True
hasNestedElt({'a': 1, 'b': ('c', (3, {'d': 4})) }) #=> True
```

one way is to iterate through elements in the dict and checking for type like below and reducing the `res` list. However it becomes unwieldy with nested elements having tuples with varying length.

```
res = []
for k, v in dct:
  if isinstance(v, (str, int):
    res.append(False)
  elif isinstance(v, tuple) & len(v) == 2:
    if isinstance(v[0], (str,int)) and isinstance(v[1], (str,int)):
      res.append(False)
    else: res.append(True)
```

Comment: Take a look at the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function…

Comment: `hasNestedElt({'a': 1, 'b': ('c', (3, 'x')) }) #=> True` why ? There is no dict nested.

Comment: `&` is bitwise; does not perform logical `and` operation. Plus, you look like you are sometimes not interested in closing paranthesis after it's opened.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have suggested, you could make use  of [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) here:

> Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False

What the below code does is iterate the values from the dictionary, if we find a `dict` return `True`. If we find a `tuple`, check if any sub elements are `tuple` or `dict`, then return `True` if we find any. Otherwise return `False` if we make to the end of the function and no nested elements have been found. This assumes your not handling `list` or any other type of collection, which is not a problem and can easily be added to the below code.

```
def hasNestedElt(dic):
    for v in dic.values():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            return True
        elif isinstance(v, tuple):
            if any(isinstance(x, (dict, tuple)) for x in v):
                return True
    return False
```

Test cases:

```
>>> hasNestedElt({'a': 1, 'b': 2}))
False
>>> hasNestedElt({'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 3} })
True
>>> hasNestedElt({'a': 1, 'b': ('c', 3) }) 
False
>>> hasNestedElt({'a': 1, 'b': ('c', 3, 'x') })
False
>>> hasNestedElt({'a': 1, 'b': ('c', (3, 'x')) })
True
>>> hasNestedElt({'a': 1, 'b': ('c', (3, {'d': 4})) })
True
```